# CFEngine policy not executed on Ubuntu nodes

Tags: ubuntu, policy, cfengine

I just started with CFEngine. I have 1 policy servers and 2 clients (Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop , Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop).

Started with creating a local policy on the Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop with CFEngine agent installed on it.

This policy removes an existing "*telnet*" client.

That local policy worked fine. So I wanted to use the policy on my policy server which then should push it to the clients after 5 minutes. This does not work.

These are the steps I did on the policy server:
**Step1:** Create a file remove_packages.cf in the /var/cfengine/masterfiles directory

```
bundle agent remove_packages
{
  methods:
      "telnet"  usebundle => package_absent("telnet");
}
```

**Step2:** vi promises.cf in the /var/cfengine/masterfiles directory and add

```
body common control

{

      bundlesequence => {
           remove_packages,
```

**Step3:** vi promises.cf in the /var/cfengine/masterfiles directory and add

```
  inputs => {
            # JF 15/08/2014 remove telnet package
                  "remove_packages.cf",

      };
```

**Step4:** Check on mistakes

```
root@ubuntu:/var/cfengine/masterfiles# cf-promises ./promises.cf
```

**Step5:** Wait 5 minutes until it replicates to the clients..

Here nothing happens at the clients ... As you can see it is still present:

```
root@ubu14client:~# which telnet
/usr/bin/telnet
```

Can somebody explain me why it does not work?

Answer (score 1):

I found in another post it had to do with "clock skew".

I have set the correct timezone for my servers and update with the ubuntu timeservers. From then everything went fine.

https://serverfault.com/questions/387675/cfengine-3-policies-slow-update-to-clients

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted your question just for the inclusion of careful step by step sequence of what you did.  I thought I would mention the remaining debugging steps you could have taken, that may have shown you what was wrong more easily (and more directly) than just googling around:

**Step 6:** Run the update policy on a bootstrapped host to pick up the changed policy files.

```
cf-agent -f update.cf
```

If you like, run it in verbose mode (with color for ease of reading):

```
cf-agent -f update.cf -v -C
```

If the update policy *just* ran, you may need to override the time locks with `-K`:

```
cf-agent -f update.cf -v -C -K
```

**Step 7:** Run the agent in verbose mode on the bootstrapped host (just the default promises.cf rather than the update policy)

```
cf-agent  ## or...
cf-agent -IC  ## for "Inform" mode, with color output, or...
cf-agent -C -v ## verbose mode, color output, or...
cf-agent -C -v -K ## Evaluate all promises even if agent just ran.
```

The verbose output can be *very* verbose, but it's good to learn to sift through it.  You can virtually always find everything you need to diagnose/debug a problem by running in verbose mode.